# DynamoDB pagination using Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, nosql

We are using boto3 for our DynamoDB and we need to do a full scan of our tables to enable to do that based on other post we need to do a pagination. However, we are unable to find a working sample of pagination. Here is what we did.

```py
import boto3
client_setting = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
paginator = client_setting.get_paginator('scan')
esk = {}
data = []
unconverted_ga = ourQuery(params1, params2)
    for page in unconverted_ga:
        data.append(page)
        esk = page['LastEvaluatedKey']
```

We dont know exactly how to make the esk as the ExclusiveStartKey of our next query. What should be the expected value of ExclusiveStartkey parameter? We are still new in DynamoDB and there's many things we need to learn including this. thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After hour of search, i've finally found a better solution. For those who are new to DynamoDB, we should'nt missed this - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html

```py
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3
import json
import decimal
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

# Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")

table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')

fe = Key('year').between(1950, 1959)
pe = "#yr, title, info.rating"
# Expression Attribute Names for Projection Expression only.
ean = { "#yr": "year", }
esk = None


response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=fe,
    ProjectionExpression=pe,
    ExpressionAttributeNames=ean
    )

for i in response['Items']:
    print(json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder))

// As long as LastEvaluatedKey is in response it means there are still items from the query related to the data
while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(
        ProjectionExpression=pe,
        FilterExpression=fe,
        ExpressionAttributeNames= ean,
        ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey']
        )

    for i in response['Items']:
        print(json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder))
```

Answer (score 7):

From the answer by Tay B at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38619425/3176550

```py
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource(
    'dynamodb',
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token,
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
    region_name=region
)
    
    table = dynamodb.Table('widgetsTableName')
    
    response = table.scan()
    data = response['Items']
    
    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        data.extend(response['Items'])
```

Comment: List does not have the method `update`. Instead of that, use `date.extend(response['Items'])`

Comment: I think the line `while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response` might need a tiny modification to `while True` loop. It could bring a problem that the last batch of records won't be processed, aka the "update" logic part.

Answer (score 6):

You can try with following code:

```py
esk = None

while True:
    scan_generator = YourTableName.scan(max_results=10, exclusive_start_key=esk)
    for item in scan_generator:
        # your code for processing
    # condition to check if entire table is scanned 
    else:
        break;

    # Load the last keys
    esk = scan_generator.kwargs['exclusive_start_key'].values()
```

Here is the reference documentation [link.](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i already found a better solution.

Comment: @vnpnlz, so what was the "better solution"?

Comment: @BruceEdge I already accepted my own answer as it was the right way to do pagination. Please refer to the link.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
import boto3

client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
marker = None

while True:
   paginator = client.get_paginator('list_tables')
   page_iterator = paginator.paginate(
       PaginationConfig={
           'MaxItems': 1000,
           'PageSize': 100,
           'StartingToken': marker})

   for page in page_iterator:
       tables=page['TableNames']
       for table in tables:
           print (table)
   try:
       marker = page['NextToken']
    except KeyError:
       sys.exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is highly recommended to add details with your code. Code only answers are not recommended by SO community. Also, please add tags with your answer. The language you have written code, please add the tag of that language. Please carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

Bit more verbose but I like it.

```py
def fetch_from_table(last_key=None):
    if last_key:
        response = table.query(
            IndexName='advertCatalogIdx',
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('sk').eq('CATALOG'),
            Limit=5,
            ExclusiveStartKey=last_key
        )
    else:
        response = table.query(
            IndexName='advertCatalogIdx',
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('sk').eq('CATALOG'),
            Limit=5
        )
        # print(response)

    for item in response['Items']:
        print(item['address'])
        print('***************************')

    return response.get('LastEvaluatedKey')


last_key = fetch_from_table()
while last_key != None:
    print("Running again : ")
    last_key = fetch_from_table(last_key)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.