# Deserialize a JSON object from DynamoDB to Opensearch?

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a DynamoDB stream that indexes and pushes data to OpenSearch via a Lambda Function that uses Boto3. The item in the stream looks like this JSON object here:

```
{
  "d8346fda0c35418580c98209df378653": {
    "M": {
      "cloudPlatformAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Google Cloud Platform"
          }
        ]
      },
      "cloudPlatformStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "AWS"
          }
        ]
      },
      "integratedDevelopmentEnvironmentAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "TextMate"
          }
        ]
      },
      "webFrameworkStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Drupal"
          }
        ]
      },
      "lastEdited": {
        "S": "13-Jun-2022 (16:34:09.233933)"
      },
      "title": {
        "S": "This is my third post (edited)"
      },
      "body": {
        "S": "asdf"
      },
      "programmingLanguageStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Python"
          }
        ]
      },
      "programmingLanguageAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Elixir"
          }
        ]
      },
      "dbAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "PostgreSQL"
          }
        ]
      },
      "databaseStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "DynamoDB"
          }
        ]
      },
      "webFrameworkAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Symfony"
          }
        ]
      },
      "timeCreated": {
        "S": "09-Jun-2022 (13:30:29.967379)"
      },
      "integratedDevelopmentEnvironment": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "TextMate"
          }
        ]
      },
      "level": {
        "S": "one"
      }
    }
  },
  "1d5c49e0fc8c458ebc2e74835831a5c8": {
    "M": {
      "cloudPlatformAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Google Cloud Platform"
          }
        ]
      },
      "cloudPlatformStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Google Cloud Platform"
          }
        ]
      },
      "integratedDevelopmentEnvironmentAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Vim"
          }
        ]
      },
      "webFrameworkStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Flask"
          }
        ]
      },
      "lastEdited": {
        "S": "13-Jun-2022 (17:30:32.808160)"
      },
      "title": {
        "S": "My First Post (edited) 1"
      },
      "body": {
        "S": "test"
      },
      "programmingLanguageStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Python"
          }
        ]
      },
      "programmingLanguageAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Erlang"
          }
        ]
      },
      "dbAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Oracle"
          }
        ]
      },
      "databaseStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Couchbase"
          }
        ]
      },
      "webFrameworkAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Spring"
          }
        ]
      },
      "timeCreated": {
        "S": "13-Jun-2022 (16:28:23.582059)"
      },
      "integratedDevelopmentEnvironment": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Vim"
          }
        ]
      },
      "awsomeBuilderStage": {
        "S": "2"
      }
    }
  },
  "bd9cc68521564858871a7482d77bb1a5": {
    "M": {
      "cloudPlatformAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Google Cloud Platform"
          }
        ]
      },
      "cloudPlatformStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Google Cloud Platform"
          }
        ]
      },
      "integratedDevelopmentEnvironmentAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Vim"
          }
        ]
      },
      "webFrameworkStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Flask"
          }
        ]
      },
      "lastEdited": {
        "S": "13-Jun-2022 (16:37:50.576490)"
      },
      "title": {
        "S": "My First Post (edited)"
      },
      "body": {
        "S": "test"
      },
      "programmingLanguageStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Python"
          }
        ]
      },
      "programmingLanguageAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Erlang"
          }
        ]
      },
      "dbAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Oracle"
          }
        ]
      },
      "databaseStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Couchbase"
          }
        ]
      },
      "webFrameworkAoi": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Spring"
          }
        ]
      },
      "timeCreated": {
        "S": "13-Jun-2022 (16:28:23.582059)"
      },
      "integratedDevelopmentEnvironment": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "Vim"
          }
        ]
      },
      "awsomeBuilderStage": {
        "S": "3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I index and push the object to OpenSearch it includes the Types associated with each nested JSON Object. For example:

```
"cloudPlatformStrength": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "AWS"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Instead of:

```
"cloudPlatformStrength": [
    "Google Cloud Platform"
   ]
```

How would I go about fixing the data being pushed to OpenSearch? Would I have to just perform ETL process on each entry? Or is there a better way to do so?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46738251/10692493) answer your question?

Comment: This post describes how to convert from a [DynamoDB item to a Python Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43755888/how-to-convert-a-boto3-dynamo-db-item-to-a-regular-dictionary-in-python/46738251#46738251).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeDeserializer

def handler(event, context):
    deserializer = TypeDeserializer()
    for record in event['Records']:

        data = {key: deserializer.deserialize(value) for key, value in 
            record['dynamodb']['NewImage'].items()}
```