# How to scan all items in dynamo db?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following method to scan all items in dynamo db table

```
async def scan_all(self, parse_item: Callable[[dict], dict], **kwargs) -> List[dict]:
    response = await self._db.scan(**kwargs)
    response_items = response.get('Items', [])
    items = list(parse_item(item) for item in response_items)
    last_evaluated_key = response.get('LastEvaluatedKey', None)
    while last_evaluated_key is not None:
        response = await self._db.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=last_evaluated_key, **kwargs)
        response_items = response.get('Items', [])
        items.extend(parse_item(item) for item in response_items)
        last_evaluated_key = response.get('LastEvaluatedKey', None)
    return items
```

Is it the right way or I can improve it? What is the best practice to use `LastEvaluatedKey`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Complete scan of dynamoDb with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780856/complete-scan-of-dynamodb-with-boto3)

Answer (score -1):

Well I am not sure it this one is better but this is how I am doing it (reading through dynamodb documentation):

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> lastKeyEvaluated = null;

    do {
        ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(TABLE_NAME)
                .withExclusiveStartKey(lastKeyEvaluated);
        ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);
        for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()) {

        }
    }while(lastKeyEvaluated != null);
```