# Can AWS Glue crawler in one account access dynamodb in another account

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

Please find below what I have tried.
Created AWS Glue crawler in one AWS account, say A.
Created IAM role in account A, to have access to dynamodb in account B.

I am trying to run crawler in account A, to access dynamodb in account B.
Its giving access denied(user:....is not authorized to perform :dynamodb:DescribeTable on resources....). However, In one of the stackover flow its mentioned "The crawler can only crawl dynamo tables in your own account. ". Is it true?

[aws glue to access/crawl dynamodb from another aws account (cross account access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233581/aws-glue-to-access-crawl-dynamodb-from-another-aws-account-cross-account-access)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a role properly in the AWS IAM to access your DynamoDB from another region, account.

Docs explanation how to pass role in AWS Glue:
[Cross-Account Cross-Region Access to DynamoDB Tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-dynamo-db-cross-account.html)