# Could not able to insert properly if items crosses 1350+ in local dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-dynamodb-local

I am using local docker setup for dynamodb. I could able to insert items when items are less it starts behaving wrong when data items goes beyond 1350 around.

```py
table = dynamodb.create_table(
        TableName='logevents',
        KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'Id',
                'KeyType': 'HASH'  # Partition key
            }
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'Id',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            }
        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput={
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 1,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 1
        }
    )
```

```py
item = {
    "log_datetime": "2019-08-04 16:16:24:302000",
    "Action": "ApiCallFailed",
    "intuit_tid": "f9d63462-51a6-463b-a19f-b5c6c7867388",
    "PackageName": "com.intuit.billingcomm.billing.ius.facade.DefaultIUSServiceFacade.fetchAllGrants",
    "FileName": "DefaultIUSServiceFacade.java",
    "PID": "9",
    "Processed_timestamp": "2019-09-05 18:17:06:515970",
    "APIKey": "GetAllGrants",
    "thread_id": "x1B35mhttps-jsse-nio-8443-exec-71\\x1B0;39m",
    "LastMessage": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is currently unavailable: status=500",
    "Exceptions": [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.MessageProcessingException",
        "com.intuit.billingcomm.billing.exception.IAMTicketClientException",
        "com.intuit.platform.integration.hats.common.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    ],
    "Event": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "CategoryLevel1": "XXXXXXXXXXX",

    "Domain": "IUS",
    "LineNo": "128",
    "CategoryLevel2": "TicketServerFailure"
    }

    for x in range(6000):
        item['Id']=str(x)
        table.put_item(
            Item=item)
    scan = table.scan(
        ProjectionExpression='#k',
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            '#k': 'Id'
        }
    )
    print(str(len(scan['Items'])))
```

If i give range 600 it shows data correctly but if i give 6000 it shows no of items 1332. is there any restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the likely scenario is that you got a paginated resulted: when the size of the scanned items cross a certain threshold you get only the the first few (in your case, the first 1332). you then need to issue subsequent calls to `scan()` to get the next chunks.

In each call (other than the first one) you need to set `ExeclusiveStartKey` with the value of `LastEvaluatedKey` from the response. If `LastEvaluatedKey` is not set, you should stop calling `scan()`. See sample code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780856/complete-scan-of-dynamodb-with-boto3).