# Error in getting JSON serializable output from Lambda from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function in python where I want to return all the contents of a DynamoDB table. I will be using this output in a GET API of AWS API Gateway, so the output needs to be ready accordingly. My lambda now looks like this:

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    table = client.Table("User")
    response = table.scan()['Items']
    
    print(json.dumps(response))
     
    return json.dumps(response)
```

The output is

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Object of type Binary is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 14, in lambda_handler\n    print(json.dumps(response))\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py\", line 231, in dumps\n    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py\", line 199, in encode\n    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py\", line 257, in iterencode\n    return _iterencode(o, 0)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py\", line 179, in default\n    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '\n"
  ]
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Can you try: `json.dumps(response, default=str)`?

Comment: "errorMessage": "__str__ returned non-string (type bytes)",
  "errorType": "TypeError",

Comment: What's the output of `print(response)`?

Answer (score 0):

The only immediate issue with you code is that you are only retrieving the first page of the scan, see the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Pagination) to learn how `scan` works. Before returning the result, you need to check if `LastEvaluatedKey` is present in the response; see also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780856/complete-scan-of-dynamodb-with-boto3).

To return all the items in your table, your code should be updated as follows:

```
import boto3
import json


client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    table = client.Table('User')
    response = table.scan()
    data = response['Items']

    while response.get('LastEvaluatedKey'):
        response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        data.extend(response['Items'])

    return json.dumps(data)
```

To debug the specific error, you need to inspect the content of the response from DynamoDB. You can check the response syntax [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#API_Scan_ResponseSyntax) to know what you should expect.