# With boto3 Dynamodb scan is there a way to get changes of events rather than last update

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Building on this answer: [Complete scan of dynamoDb with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780856/complete-scan-of-dynamodb-with-boto3)

What I would like to achieve is to also get the historical changes on each item. For example if item 1 has had three changes over time:

```json
{
"item" : 1
"x" : "abc"
"time" : 1
}
```

```json
{
"item" : 1
"x" : "efg"
"time" : 2
}
```

```json
{
"item" : 1
"x" : "hij"
"time" : 3
}
```

The scan will only give me the latest one, i.e.

```json
{
"item" : 1
"x" : "hij"
"time" : 3
}
```

Is there a way to get the previous two changes as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the previous two changes as well?

Sadly, there is not unless you implement such a solution for that yourself. Probably you would have to use [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) to stream changes to a lambda function, and then store all historical values in some other database.

Comment: Yeap that is what I am using now, but DynamoDB Streams doesn't offer that capability either as far as I can tell. It will only publish only from the time you deploy the Stream and onwards.

Comment: @and_apo I wrote you need to develop fully **custom solution** for that yourself. DynamoDB streams would be small part of it.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. How would a custom solution work if the only way to query Dynamo(except DynamoDB streams) is the scan and the scan gives you only the latest change?

Comment: @and_apo You would use DynamoDB streams to store and record any changes in your database.

Comment: yes I get that :) but what about records and changes to those records before enabling DynamoDB streams? Are those stored somewhere that I can get or am I stuck with the latest update for each one? That is the essence of this question

Comment: @and_apo No you cant any past records, unless you kept backups of your table.