# Scan all records in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a Python program to scan all the records from DynamoDB table, however its not retrieving all the records. I am using LastEvaluatedKey to scan all the records due to 1mb record retrieval limitation. it looks like LastEvaluatedKey is not present in my response. Can someone please help?

```
import json
import sys
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    table = dynamodb.Table('Your_Table_Name')

    queryCount = 1

    response = table.scan()
    print("Total Records:-", response['ScannedCount'])

    #Extract the Results
    items = response['Items']
    for item in items:
        print(item)
    
    queryCount = queryCount + 1

    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        print('1---------')
        key = response['LastEvaluatedKey']
        response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=key)
        items = response['Items']
        for item in items:
        queryCount = queryCount + 1
        print("2---------")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complete scan of dynamoDb with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780856/complete-scan-of-dynamodb-with-boto3)

Comment: @lvthillo, unfortunately its not working. I am able to display 1MB size of data, however not the further data. What i observed that my response does not contain LastEvaluatedKey at all, hence "  while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:" loop is not getting executed. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is being returned?

Comment: i am simply getting response with all details however LastEvaluatedKey is missing.

Comment: You're certain that you have more data to scan because your tooling tells you otherwise?

Comment: I guess, i did not have enough data so LastEvaluatedKey  was not present in Response. When i ran against large volume of data, i could found LastEvaluatedKey .