# Issue in scanning dynamodb records with date filter using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb table with a huge amount of data. I am trying to filter the ones with `creationDate` greater than a particular value. Its returning values, but the total size of data returned is less than what is actually there in the database.

Is there anything wrong in the date filter, or do I have to give any specific format for the date filter because the
`creationDate` is stored in the database with the format as : "**2022-03-25T02:29:12.591**"

```py
table = dynamodb.Table('table_log')
fe=Attr("creationDate").gte("2022-03-25")

response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=fe
    )

data = response['Items']

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=fe,
        ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey']
        )
data.extend(response['Items'])
```

Comment: Figured out the issue. It was a small mistake. I had kept the code to append the response to the list out of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

That's b/c scan has a limit on how much data it will return. If you take a look at the documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan), you can see that  1MB is set as the max return amount. As you need all of the data, you will have to paginate. See also [other responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780856/complete-scan-of-dynamodb-with-boto3) to similar question.

Comment: Thanks for posting, I agree with you - yes the scan function has a limitation, but i have made use of  `LastEvaluatedKey` to scan all the results. However, I figured out the issue. It was a small mistake from my side. I had kept the code to append the response to the list out of the while loop. Thanks.

Comment: @SachinBose I missed that, glad you solved it.