# dynamodb query is not returning all records

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Hi I am using boto3 to get all record of DynamoDB.

```
 response = table.query(
        IndexName='GSI3',
        KeyConditionExpression="GSI3_ACCOUNT_PK = 2"
        ProjectionExpression='USER_ID, USER_TYPE',    
    )
```

but it's returning almost 2130 records . what I should do to get all records ? any help would be highly appreciated .

Comment: See [Paginating table query results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html).

Comment: @jarmod hi thanks for comment . I am very new in this and not able to do this in boto3 . can you please show a working example please ?

Comment: Example: https://beabetterdev.com/2022/02/07/how-to-query-dynamodb-with-boto3/

Comment: @jarmod not getting  `LastEvaluatedKey` in response :(

Comment: Your query is for a specific subset of items, namely those with GSI3_ACCOUNT_PK = 2. How sure are you that there are more matching items than are returned from the query? What evidence do you have for this?

Comment: @jarmod  I ran query on aws dynamo dashboard there are latest record aswell. but in boto3 I am not getting those records . so It's my assumption that maybe due to size limit these are not coming

Comment: I'd double-check things here. If the table's not too large, for example, use PartiQL to do a SQL query or export the table and then do some local validation on the contents e.g. how many items have GSI3_ACCOUNT_PK = 2? Also look into boto3 paginators (examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780856/complete-scan-of-dynamodb-with-boto3)).

Comment: @jarmod thanks for help. able to do now. working