# How to use pagination in dynamodb in boto3 using the SCAN method?

Tags: pagination, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-local

I'm trying to use 'LastEvaluatedKey' with a scan method in dynamo, but I'm not able to pull data from other pages, just one.

I also asked to print the value of 'LastEvaluatedKey' and the values ​​always remain the same, it's as if it doesn't leave the first pagination and I don't understand why,

```
resp = table.scan(AttributesToGet=['name','email'])`

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' resp:     

    count=0     
    while count < len(resp.get('Items')):
       print(resp.get('Items')[count].get('name'), ",",
       resp.get('Items')[count].get('email'))  
       count +=1
```

Comment: Guys, i'm trying to concat code correctly on stackOverflow but it's hard, sorry. It could be easier and simplier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complete scan of dynamoDb with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780856/complete-scan-of-dynamodb-with-boto3)

Comment: With paginated APIs, you call the API multiple times, once per page. So, in this case, you would call `scan` multiple times in a loop, each time providing the 'last evaluated key', until a response indicates there are no more pages. You're only calling `scan` once, so you will only get the first page.

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('mytable')

response = table.scan(AttributesToGet=['name','email'])

data = response['Items']

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(AttributesToGet=['name','email'],Exclusive Start Key=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    data.extend(response['Items'])
```

Comment: Could you tell me what means 'data.extend(response['Items']'?

Comment: That's where you add more items to the list of items you're holding, the results. Every page from DynamoDB returns 1MB of data and you add those items to the list. When all the data is read, the list `data` will hold all your results.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_extend.asp

Comment: I did what you explained, but when I print the 'LastEvaluateKey' continues to repeat itself with the same values, it doesn't change.

Comment: [Fixing] The process was finished, 'Killed' appeared at the end of the terminal, does this mean the end of the process or is it some kind of error?

Comment: I can't help if I can't see your code. Update your answer.